# Printing Popup Window after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've spent more than 5 hours on this, I'm trying to load a link on a popup window and after loading I want to print it.

so what I did is the following

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function printer(){
            var link = 'file:///C:\\page0339.swf';
            w = window.open(link, "_blank", "location=1,scrollbars=1,menuBar=1,width=600, height=400");
            w.onload = function() { 
                this.print();
                this.close();
            };
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#print").click(function () {
                printer();
            });

        });

</script>
<input type ="button" id = "print" value = 'print' />
```

inside onload I've tried `alert` message and it shows up but both `this.print();this.close();` are never called, and I didn't see any javascript error.
so How I can call print function inside onload??

Comment: What happens when you click the button?

Comment: @KevinHooke a new pop up loaded,but print and close actions didnt work. Plus if I add alert in the if conditional its shown. And when I get the print and close out of the if conditional they works. So the if conditional works and the print+ close works outside if-block. But in side if-block they are not working

Answer (score 1):

Seems like attaching an onload after already opening the window is the wrong way to go.  Instead of

```
w.onload = function() { 
                this.print();
                this.close();
            };
```

Have you tried this?

```
w.print();
w.close();
```

Comment: Yes Ive tried its not working, even w.window.print();

Comment: But when i put them out of the if conditional they works fine